# How to replace two chars with one char?

Tags: c, loops, char, c-strings

So I'm trying to replace `cc` with `&` in a sentence (eg: `"Hi this is Mark cc Alice"`). So far I have this code where it replaces the first `c` with `&` but the second `c` is still there. How would I get rid of the second `c`?

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "Hi this is Mark cc Alice";
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] == 'c' && str[i + 1] == 'c') {
            str[i] = '&';  
            //str[i + 1] = ' ';
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n-------------------------------------");
    printf("\nString After Replacing 'cc' by '&'");
    printf("\n-------------------------------------\n");
    printf("%s\n",str);
    return str;
}
```

The input is:

```
Hi this is Mark cc Alice
```

The Output is:

```
Hi this is Mark &c Alice
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just shuffle it over one spot using a generic "move back" function:

```c
void shunt(char* dest, char* src) {
  while (*dest) {
    *dest = *src;
    ++dest;
    ++src;
  }
}
```

Where you can use it like this:

```c
int main(){
  char str[] = "Hi this is Mark cc Alice";

  for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i) {
    if (str[i] == 'c' && str[i+1] == 'c') {
      str[i]='&';

      shunt(&str[i+1], &str[i+2]);
    }
  }

  printf("\n-------------------------------------");
  printf("\nString After Replacing 'cc' by '&'");
  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n");
  printf("%s\n",str);

  // main() should return a valid int status code (0 = success)
  return 0;
}
```

Note the switch from the messy `int` declaration + `while` + increment into one `for` loop. This would be even less messy using a `char*` pointer instead:

```
for (char* s = str; *s; ++s) {
  if (s[0] == 'c' && s[1] == 'c'){
    *s = '&';

    shunt(&s[1], &s[2]);
  }
}
```

When working with C strings it's important to be comfortable working with pointers as that can save you a *lot* of hassle.

> You should also familiarize yourself with the C Standard Library so you can use tools like [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) instead of writing your own equivalent of same. Here `strstr(str, "cc")` could have helped.

Comment: You could just use `memmove(str + i + 1, str + i + 2, strlen(str + i + 2) + 1);`

Comment: @chqrlie Wasn't sure how safe `memmove` would be with overlapping source/target.

Comment: `memmove` is specifically designed to handle overlapping areas correctly, unlike `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to shift the whole array to left. A simple way of doing that is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_SIZE 25

int main(){
  char str[STR_SIZE] = "Hi this is Mark cc Alice";
  int i=0,j=0;

  while(str[i]!='\0'){
    if(str[i]=='c' && str[i+1]=='c'){ 
      str[i]='&';
      for (j=i+1; j<STR_SIZE-1; j++) /* Shifting the array to the left */
      {
          str[j]=str[j+1];
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
  printf("\n-------------------------------------");
  printf("\nString After Replacing 'cc' by '&'");
  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n");
  printf("%s\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `STR_SIZE` here. If anything that's asking for trouble if that string ever gets longer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 2 finger method: use separate index variables to read and write characters in the same array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "Hi this is Mark cc Alice";
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] == 'c' && str[i + 1] == 'c') {
            str[j++] = '&';
            i += 2;
        } else {
            str[j++] = str[i++];
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';  // set the null terminator that was not copied.

    printf("\n-------------------------------------");
    printf("\nString After Replacing 'cc' by '&'");
    printf("\n-------------------------------------\n");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without changing much of you code you can also do it below way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char str[] = "Hi this is Mark cc Alice";
  int i=0;
  while(str[i]!='\0')
  {
    if(str[i]=='c' && str[i+1]=='c')
    {
      str[i]='&'; 
      // after replacing the first 'c' increment the i, so it will point to next c.
      i++;
      break;
      //str[i+1]=' ';
    }
    i++;
  }
  // replace previous char with next char until null
  while(str[i]!='\0')
  {
      str[i] = str[i+1];
      i++;
  }
  printf("\n-------------------------------------");
  printf("\nString After Replacing 'cc' by '&'");
  printf("\n-------------------------------------\n");
  printf("%s\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also @RainbowUnicorn, you are returning `str` at the end of main, that is not correct, just use `return 0;`